# CRM 2013 Updating a incident field during the Close Message

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to update a particular field when a case is closed. I have the Plugin registered as a Pre Operation event on the Close message. My registered event is as below.

```
base.RegisteredEvents.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string, Action<LocalPluginContext>>(20, "Close", "incident", new Action<LocalPluginContext>(ExecutePreCaseCloseFolder)));
```

And, within the Execute method, I have the following code

```
Entity incidentResolution = (context.InputParameters != null && context.InputParameters.Contains("IncidentResolution")) ? (Entity)context.InputParameters["IncidentResolution"] : null;

Incident incident = (localContext.OrganizationService.Retrieve("incident", ((EntityReference)incidentResolution["incidentid"]).Id, new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet(true))).ToEntity<Incident>();

string documentSetURL = CloseCase(incident);
incident.new_documentSetURL = documentSetURL;
```

However, it is not updating the field. My plugin gets triggered when I close a case and I am able to debug and see that an updated documentSetURL is being applied to incident.new_documentSetURL.

So, why is it not updating.

If I am not wrong, the Pre-Operation is after the validation is completed but before the values are being saved. And, I am updating a value before it is being saved. Am I not correct in my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

You can't update an incident when it is closed. So you have to update your case before the IncidentResolution has been created.

In your plugin, you have to update your case that you retrieved: `service.Update(incident);`. With this you ensure that the case is updated before the creation of incident resolution.

Take a look at http://nickhollis.blogspot.pt/2013/04/crm-2011-plugin-to-update-case-incident.html.